# Copying 2d array elements from one to the other

Tags: java, matrix

I want to find adjugate matrix from a n x n matrix,

e.g the matrix is 4x4

```
{0,  11, 15, 11},
{7,  0, 1 , 8},
{4, 19, 0 , 6},
{2, 3, 5, 0}
```

This is my output

Matrix One

```
Loop: 1
0 1 8 19 0 6 3 5 0 
Loop: 2
7 1 8 4 0 6 2 5 0 
Loop: 3
7 0 8 4 19 6 2 3 0 
Loop: 4
7 0 1 4 19 0 2 3 5 
Loop: 5
11 15 11 19 0 6 3 5 0 
Loop: 6
0 15 11 4 0 6 2 5 0 
Loop: 7
0 11 11 4 19 6 2 3 0 
Loop: 8
0 11 15 4 19 0 2 3 5 
Loop: 9
11 15 11 0 1 8 3 5 0 
Loop: 10
0 15 11 7 1 8 2 5 0 
Loop: 11
0 11 11 7 0 8 2 3 0 
Loop: 12
0 11 15 7 0 1 2 3 5 
Loop: 13
11 15 11 0 1 8 19 0 6 
Loop: 14
0 15 11 7 1 8 4 0 6 
Loop: 15
0 11 11 7 0 8 4 19 6 
Loop: 16
0 11 15 7 0 1 4 19 0
```

I stored the values into another 2darray(matrixTwo) to calculate the determinant to find the inverse matrix but found out that what is stored in my matrix two isn't the same as the output above.why is value stored different? please help

```
Matrix Two
Loop: 1
0 11 15 11 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
Loop: 2
7 0 1 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
Loop: 3
4 19 0 6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
Loop: 4
2 3 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
Loop: 5
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
Loop: 6
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
Loop: 7
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
Loop: 8
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
Loop: 9
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
Loop: 10
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
Loop: 11
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
Loop: 12
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
Loop: 13
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
Loop: 14
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
Loop: 15
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
Loop: 16
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

My Codes

```
public class Matrix {
    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        int matrix[][]= { {0,  11, 15, 11},
                           {7,  0, 1 , 8},
                           {4, 19, 0 , 6},
                           {2, 3, 5, 0} 
        };

        int matrixTwo[][] = new int[(matrix.length) * (matrix.length)][(matrix.length) * (matrix.length)];
        int ctr = 0;
        System.out.println("Matrix One");
        for(int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++) {
                ctr++;
                System.out.println("\nLoop: " + ctr);
                for(int row = 0;row < matrix.length; row++) {
                    for(int col = 0; col < matrix[row].length; col++) {
                                    if(row != i && col != j) {
                                System.out.print(matrix[row][col] + " ");
                            matrixTwo[row][col] = matrix[row][col];
                    }
                }
            }           
        }
    }

    int ctrTwo = 0;
    System.out.println("\n\nMatrix Two");
    for(int row = 0; row < matrixTwo.length; row++) {
        ctrTwo++;
        System.out.println("Loop: " + ctrTwo);
        for(int col = 0; col < matrixTwo.length; col++) {
            System.out.print(matrixTwo[row][col] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These is different because they are printed in different orders

For a example,

From the matrix one

```
Loop: 1
0 1 8 19 0 6 3 5 0
```

prints

```
Loop: 1
matrix[1][1] = 0 matrix[1][2] = 1 matrix[1][3] = 8 matrix[2][1] = 19 matrix[2][2] = 0 matrix[2][3] = 6 matrix[3][1] = 3 matrix[3][2] = 5 matrix[3][3] = 0
```

From the matrixTwo

```
Loop: 1
0 11 15 11 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

prints

```
Loop: 1
matrixTwo[0][0] = 0 matrixTwo[0][1] = 11 matrixTwo[0][2] = 15 matrixTwo[0][3] = 11 matrixTwo[0][4] = 0 matrixTwo[0][5] = 0 matrixTwo[0][6] = 0 matrixTwo[0][7] = 0 matrixTwo[0][8] = 0 matrixTwo[0][9] = 0 matrixTwo[0][10] = 0 matrixTwo[0][11] = 0 matrixTwo[0][12] = 0 matrixTwo[0][13] = 0 matrixTwo[0][14] = 0 matrixTwo[0][15] = 0
```

Use `System.out.print("matrix[" + row + "][" + col  + "] = " + matrix[row][col] + " ");`. You can see the difference

Answer (score 0):

right now, you are simply copying the first matrix into the second.

here is the testclass where you can see it:

```
public class test2 {

    int matrix[][] = { { 0, 11, 15, 11 }, { 7, 0, 1, 8 }, { 4, 19, 0, 6 },
            { 2, 3, 5, 0 } };

    int matrixTwo[][] = new int[(matrix.length) * (matrix.length)][(matrix.length)
            * (matrix.length)];

    public test2() {
        int ctr = 0;
        System.out.println("Matrix One");
        for (int row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < matrix.length; col++) {
                ctr++;
                System.out.println("\nLoop: " + ctr);
                for (int row1 = 0; row1 < matrix.length; row1++) {
                    for (int col1 = 0; col1 < matrix[row1].length; col1++) {
                        if (row1 != row && col1 != col) {
                            System.out.print(matrix[row1][col1] + " ");
                            matrixTwo[row1][col1] = matrix[row1][col1];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        int ctrTwo = 0;
        System.out.println("\n\nMatrix Two");
        for (int row = 0; row < matrixTwo.length; row++) {
            ctrTwo++;
            System.out.println("Loop: " + ctrTwo);
            for (int col = 0; col < matrixTwo.length; col++) {
                System.out.print(matrixTwo[row][col] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        printArray(matrix);
        System.out.println();
        printArray(matrixTwo);
    }

    public void printArray(int[][] matrix) {
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.printf("%3d", matrix[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        new test2();

    }
}
```

the result:

matrix:

```
  0 11 15 11
  7  0  1  8
  4 19  0  6
  2  3  5  0
```

matrixTwo:

```
  0 11 15 11  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  7  0  1  8  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  4 19  0  6  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  2  3  5  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

this is not what you wanted to do.
think about what is done in this line: `matrixTwo[row][col] = matrix[row][col];`